# Drawing overlays in mapbox

Tags: mapbox

Hi I want to draw overlays in map box.

1. May I know if Map box supports drawing overlay.
2. May i also know whether image,text,table overlays supported in map box.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- [Leaflet Draw](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-draw/)

and Yes --  [Image Overlay](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-imageoverlay/)